According to mainstream Christian Protestants, Is there a waiting place for the saints and the wicked where they are immediately received after death?
From the parable of the rich man and Lazarus, Jesus taught that both died but went to different destinations in the afterlife. Lazarus was comforted in Abraham's bossom which is paradise and the rich man received in Hades. These two destinations are temporary as the saints in paradise will later move to the new heaven and the new earth while those who wait in Hades will move from there to the lake of fire. I do believe that paradise is full of the saints from the old testament and the new testament such Moses, Elijah, Elisha and the rest. They also await the ultimate resurrection of every human being that has ever walked over the face of the earth on the last day. Are these destinations real or Jesus was symbolically speaking about what will happen after judgment where some people will be exalted to life and others sent to the lake of fire ?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Based on what Jesus told Lazarus, mainstream Protestant Christians understand that after the death of the body, the soul awaits the resurrection and judgment.  As a Protestant of the Reformed tradition, I do not take Luke 16:19-31 as a parable
While the rich man had lived for the day and only focused on life here on earth, Lazarus endured many hardships while trusting in God. So, verses 22 and 23 are significant: “So it was that the beggar died, and was carried by the angels to Abraham’s bosom. The rich man also died and was buried. And being in torments in Hades, he lifted up his eyes and saw Abraham afar off, and Lazarus in his bosom.”
Jesus spoke of a place of bliss (Abraham's bosom/paradise) and a place of torment.  Given who Jesus is, he knew what he was talking about and his warning was clear.
Both paradise and hell are perceived as “temporary holding places” until the day when Jesus Christ comes back to judge the world based on whether or not individuals have believed in Him.
At the resurrection all will be sent to their eternal destination, the wicked to the lake of fire (Revelation 20:11-15), and the righteous to a new heaven and a new earth (Revelation 21—22).
Jesus also said this in Luke 12:4-5:

"My friends, do not be afraid of those who kill the body, and after that have no more that they can do. But I will show you whom you should fear: Fear Him who, after He has killed, has power to cast into hell; yes, I say to you, fear Him!"

Our choices while alive affect our eternal destination.

Thanks Lesley for this truth

...but Revelation suggests that the result of Judgment will be a surprise to those who are judged. How do you reconcile that with a "temporary holding place" whose nature seems to reveal the outcome of Judgment?

@Matthew - The apocalyptic language of Revelation suggests many things. My answer is focused on the words of Jesus which preceded the revelation given to the apostle John. A separate question on what Revelation suggests may be appropriate to ask.
